# Is it ok to ask a potential employer if one's application is still being considered?

Tags: interviewing, recruitment

I had two interviews in one week, with different managers, at this consulting firm. I thought they went pretty well. The second interview was over 2 weeks ago, and I have not been recontacted since, although the possibility of a third interview, with a senior consultant this time, was mentioned during the second interview.

I know that many companies often do not answer at all to applications that they don't find interesting. But is it normal to just go silent after two interviews with a candidate? I don't have much experience with these recruitment processes since I've been working for the same employer since I've graduated.

Should I just accept that I'm no longer being considered for the position? Or should I just wait? Or is it acceptable to shoot an email to my contact and ask them about it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: @gnat Thank you for the link, it is related and helpful, but I'm not sure it answers the question - the person had an interview and then an expected date the same week for a decision about an offer, I have no expected date and I've just been without news for 2 weeks.

Answer (score 1):

> But is it normal to just go silent after two interviews with a candidate? I don't have much experience with these recruitment processes since I've been working for the same employer since I've graduated.

A few months ago I had 6 (!) interviews with 6 different people for a mid/senior-level position and still the company just ghosted me.

> Should I just accept that I'm no longer being considered for the position? Or should I just wait? Or is it acceptable to shoot an email to my contact and ask them about it?

Only contact them if you have a reason, mostly another company that offered you a job, which you need to notify whether you are accepting or not.

Otherwise waiting is good, since you're avoiding getting on HR person's/ hiring manager's nerves.

You should always assume you haven't got the job anyway, unless you hold a signed contract in your hands.

Answer (score 0):

Most people follow BigMadAndy's way of thinking, which is very reasonable. Let me be the devil's advocate here. In your mind, you're still with the job/interviews and cannot let go of the possibility of getting a response. Well, if not asking probably won't give you the job, why not try to get an answer to your question?

Although this might be different between countries, I would wait for a certain time (you've been waiting two weeks now, that's fine) and then find a way to contact them. The reason and medium for this contact can be different as well:

*Medium*

- If you have a telephone number, call them. You'll have a higher possibility of receiving an answer and, if you've been nice at the phone, your name rings again in their minds
- If you don't have a phone number and can only send an email, that's the second option. Often emails are not responded to (which I still find very inappropriate, especially after actual interviews), so don't expect an answer. But: nothing ventured, nothing gained.

*Reason*

- Asking for the third interview is probably a bad idea
- Asking for whether they made a decision is too. They either made up their minds already and didn't send you an email or haven't made a decision yet (and you might get onto someone's nerves as BigMadAndy mentioned).
- Asking when you could expect a response to your interview of two weeks ago, is a lot better. You're not asking for the job, you show that you still have an interest in it and you're kindly asking for when you can expect a response.

This last option can still lead to no answer, but at least you tried. Or it can return a 'you're not the one', which is still a response you would like to have. Or they respond they need some more time. That's the most hopeful option.

Again, this might be seen as a bold action in some countries (in the Netherlands, we're often seen as direct). Both seeking for an answer to your question and waiting until they come to you have risks, advantages, and drawbacks.